# R ggplot2 not display unicode font from dataframe correctly

Tags: mysql, r, ggplot2, unicode, char

Please help check this issue and recommend any library to make it work. I have used showtext library but not help.

[image]

[image]

### Sample Data & Code

```
category_name     total_readers
មនោសញ្ចេតនា​            267867
ស្នេហា                 239880
ព្រឺព្រួច                 222031
អាថ៌កំបាំង               127858
គុននិយម               101888

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(area = total_readers, fill = category_name, label = category_name)) +
  geom_treemap() + theme(legend.position = "bottom", ) +
  geom_treemap_text(fontface = "italic", colour = "white", place = "centre", grow = FALSE)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not helpful because we cannot copy/paste that into R for testing.

Comment: @MrFlick I have edited my questions with sample data and code so that you can reproduce it.

Comment: This seems to be about dataframes, not databases.

Comment: @RickJames I have check the dataframes and the char seem to be ok. Issue only when I plot it, the char seem to go wrong